# Pros and cons of AWS Device Farm?

Tags: quality-assurance, mobile-automation, aws, mobile-applications

My team is deciding whether or not to use AWS Device Farm, and I was curious if anyone here has experience with it testing their mobile apps and what they like/ dislike about it?

thanks!

Comment: Are you asking specifically about AWS or about device farms in general ? can you add more information about what are your needs ? the question as it is seems to wide and general.

Answer (score 1):

I did a Cost-Benefit-Analysis a few years ago (so take it with a grain of salt) and found

*AWS Device Farm* - Worked really well for Android but didn't screen record iOS runs and the remote control mode was really laggy.

*Xamarin Cloud* - Worked well but was expensive and instrumenting was a chore. I don't recall a remote control mode.

*TestObject* - Had everything we were looking for; iOS and Android log and videos, remote control mode, and was relatively inexpensive.

Please keep in mind that your requirements might be different and the products might have evolved since 2017. The main benefit of the cloud devices is saving on costs of furnishing devices to the DEV/QA teams and the ability to try to reproduce issues on more devices. If you only have to support one or two devices it might be more cost-effective to plug those devices into a Mac Mini running Appium Server.